# Can a Delphi DLL be PInvoked and used in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, interop, pinvoke

Im trying to migrate an application built in c++ builder. Our client wants us to import VCL functionalities instead of finding .net equivalents or create a new one due to time constraints.

I tried to pinvoke rtl100.bpl's ExtractRelativePath function which have AnsiString as a return and parameters. I then used IntPtr to pass and get the strings but an AccessViolationException occurs when the API is called.

Here is the function prototype from rtl100.bpl

```
PACKAGE AnsiString __fastcall ExtractRelativePath(const AnsiString BasrName, AnsiString DestName);
```

This is how i pinvoked it.

```
[DllImport("rtl100.bpl", EntryPoint = "@Sysutils@ExtractRelativePath$qqrx17System@AnsiString1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
Internal static extern IntPtr ExtractRelativePath(IntPtr BaseName, IntPtr DestName);
```

And of course i will allocate and deallocate the intptrs using thr marshal class.

The question is, can delphi libraries really be used in c#? Most of its API uses AnsiString which is a native delphi string. Or maybe we should start considering using .net functions?

Thanks

Comment: You're using a wrong calling convention. It seems however that you cannot call this Delphi function, because the `CallingConvention.FastCall` is not supported in .NET.

Comment: @Ðаn: If the DLL uses types like `AnsiString` and Delphi/C++Builder's `fastcall`, there is no way this will be compilable or even accessible in C++/CLI. It can be wrapped in C++Builder and be made to use primitive types (POD) types instead, and that can easily be exported and then marshelled by .NET. But if this uses AnsiString a lot, it probably doesn't make sense to use the DLL at all.

Comment: See David Heffernan's answer. This is not viable at all. RTL100.BPL is a DLL written in Delphi (Object Pascal), and with extras (more or less like an assembly) to make it directly usable and linkable by Delphi and C++Builder **of the same version only**. C++Builder is the only C++ I know that can directly link to such BPLs. And this is an entire runtime library, with hundreds of functions, which **all** use an incompatible fastcall calling convention and pass around several Delphi/C++Builder specific types that have no equivalent in other compilers/toolchains. Also look at David's point 3.

Comment: @Ðаn: Yes, you can generally find a way to use a Delphi and or C++Builder DLL, but this is not a normal DLL, it is a BPL, a special DLL chockfull of metadata to make it directly -- and only -- usable from Delphi (and its sibling, C++Builder). Only these two languages can actually use such a BPL. It is not meant to be used as a plain DLL, it is a runtime for a specific version of Delphi.

Comment: @dymanoid: Actually, even if it were supported, it would still not help here. C++Builder's `__fastcall` is not the same as MS's `__fastcall`. They both use registers to pass arguments, but not the same registers. C++Builder's `__fastcall` is actually the same as Delphi's default `register` calling convention.

Comment: So when this .bpl is wrapped in c++ builder and turned into a DLL, only then it can be used in c#? If so, then I'm kind of worried about the time it will take to create two wrappers instead of making our own c# implementations. Oh and btw, thank you guys!

Comment: Oh sorry, forget what i just said. i missed @rudy's comment. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

1. The Delphi RTL uses a register based calling convention that is not supported by other tool chains.
2. `AnsiString` is a Delphi specific type that cannot be passed to and from other tool chains.
3. This particular function allocates heap memory that the caller must dispose of. Your C# code is in no position to do so.

I think it likely that you are going to need to re-align your client's expectations. What you are attempting is not viable.

Comment: Thank you very much @david i knew it'll be a pain the moment i saw it's a .bpl. I just tried wrapping this dll without considering the limitations of .net interop. Guess i just needed another dev's perspective. Thanks again!